# Redis Lettuce Publish

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I'm working on JDK 1.8 and I'm not able to figure out why "*publish*" is not working. The Redis "*set*" command is working for the data.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create(redisURI);
connection = redisClient.connect();
String l_message = l_eventObject.toString();
connection.sync().publish(l_namespace, l_message);
connection.flushCommands(); // added this to see if this works
```

**Debug output from log:**

```
01:25:44.826 [Thread-3] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.RedisChannelHandler - dispatching command AsyncCommand [type=PUBLISH, output=IntegerOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]

01:25:44.826 [Thread-3] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379, epid=0x1] write() writeAndFlush command AsyncCommand [type=PUBLISH, output=IntegerOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]

01:25:44.827 [Thread-3] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379, epid=0x1] write() done

01:25:44.827 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379, chid=0x1] write(ctx, AsyncCommand [type=PUBLISH, output=IntegerOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command], promise)

01:25:44.829 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandEncoder - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379] writing command AsyncCommand [type=PUBLISH, output=IntegerOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]

01:25:44.830 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379, chid=0x1] Received: 4 bytes, 1 commands in the stack

01:25:44.831 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379, chid=0x1] Stack contains: 1 commands

01:25:44.831 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine - Decode AsyncCommand [type=PUBLISH, output=IntegerOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]

01:25:44.831 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine - Decoded AsyncCommand [type=PUBLISH, output=IntegerOutput [output=0, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command], empty stack: true

01:25:44.831 [Thread-3] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379, epid=0x1] flushCommands()

01:25:44.831 [Thread-3] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.DefaultEndpoint - [channel=0xb75e3dc8, /10.1.1.202:59522 -> /10.1.1.44:6379, epid=0x1] flushCommands() Flushing 0 commands
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Checked the Redis database for entires - there were none - but, when publishing events from Node.js programs I am able to see entries even though there are no subscribers connected.

Comment: does this have something to do with hot/cold publisher?

Comment: publishing works - I created a subscriber and checked.  I would still like to know why the event was not listed in Redis but, when publishing via C# or Node.js the event is listed in Redis?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
async.multi();
async.publish(l_namespace, l_message);
async.set(l_key, l_message); // for late subscribers to catch up
async.exec();
```